# Обьединение нескольких рядов в один

Tags: sql, mariadb

#### Список таблиц:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `matches` (
    `auto_id` INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date`    DATE NOT NULL,
    `name`    TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_matches` (
    `auto_id`     INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `match_id`    INT  NOT NULL REFERENCES `matches` (`auto_id`),
    `team_name`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `team_points` INT  NOT NULL
);
```

#### Значения:

```sql
SELECT * FROM team_matches;

+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------+
| auto_id | match_id | team_name          | team_points |
+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------+
|       1 |        1 | Тестовая команда 1 |        2500 |
|       2 |        1 | Тестовая команда 2 |        1500 |
|       3 |        2 | Тестовая команда 3 |        2500 |
|       4 |        2 | Тестовая команда 4 |        1500 |
+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------+
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM matches;

+---------+------------+-----------------+
| auto_id | date       | name            |
+---------+------------+-----------------+
|       1 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч   |
|       2 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч 2 |
+---------+------------+-----------------+
```

#### Обьединение:

```sql
SELECT team_matches.*, matches.* FROM team_matches JOIN matches ON team_matches.match_id = matches.auto_id;

+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------------+
| auto_id | match_id | team_name          | team_points | auto_id | date       | name            |
+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------------+
|       1 |        1 | Тестовая команда 1 |        2500 |       1 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч   |
|       2 |        1 | Тестовая команда 2 |        1500 |       1 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч   |
|       3 |        2 | Тестовая команда 3 |        2500 |       2 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч 2 |
|       4 |        2 | Тестовая команда 4 |        1500 |       2 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч 2 |
+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------------+
```

Если присмотреться, то можно заметить, что `team_matches.match_id` и `matches.auto_id` связаны между собой (так же в самой таблице есть `REFERENCES`), и я хочу обьединить не строки, а именно ряды.

То есть в ответе я желаю получить:

```sql
+------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+
|    date    | name            | match_id | team_one           | one_points | team_two           | two_points |
+------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+
| 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч   | 1        | Тестовая команда 1 | 2500       | Тестовая команда 2 | 1500       |
| 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч 2 | 2        | Тестовая команда 3 | 2500       | Тестовая команда 4 | 1500       |
+------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+
```

То есть я хочу обьединить ряды:

```sql
|       1 |        1 | Тестовая команда 1 |        2500 |       1 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч   |
|       2 |        1 | Тестовая команда 2 |        1500 |       1 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч   |
```

И

```sql
|       3 |        2 | Тестовая команда 3 |        2500 |       2 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч 2 |
|       4 |        2 | Тестовая команда 4 |        1500 |       2 | 2022-11-05 | Тестовый матч 2 |
```

В одну, однако в интернете при поиске как их обьединять, интернет находит очень много как можно обьединить строки, но не ряды.

Использую:

```
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.6.8-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
```

Это конечно же можно сделать и используя язык программирования, к примеру `php`, однако база данных это сделает гораздо быстрее, чем `foreach`

Comment: А чем строка отличается от ряда ? Такого понятия как ряд не существует. Вы что то свое так назваете

Comment: Как по мне, тут обычный group by по полям таблицы matches

Comment: Строка: это как я понимаю 'Одна строка' + 'Вторая строка'. Но плюсование строк - это обычно сложение нескольких значений в одно единое, а я хочу скажем так переместить местами колонки/ряды.

Comment: group by не даст результата обьединения, он может посчитать количество если использвать sum/count, однако тут не цифры, а строки

Comment: Хотя нет. видимо надо к matches выполнить два раза join team_matches только встает вопрос какие условия там написать. какая из команд должна быть слева, а какая справа. нужен четкий признак. (Если что, признак "у левой команды id меньше чем у правой" я считаю достаточно четким, но может есть что то более приближенное к предметной области)

Comment: Какой командой окажется первая, а какой вторая - роли не играет.
Хоть 'команда 1', 'команда 2', хоть 'команда 2', 'команда 1'.
В данном случае какая команда будет на первом месте, а какая на втором не важно

Comment: Если вы присмотритесь, то увидете, что я хочу обьединить matches с team_matches, и хочу обьединить конкретно team_name и team_points, то есть за место team_name и team_points я хочу получить `team_one_name` и `team_one_points` + `team_two_name` и `team_two_points`, то есть я другими словами обьединяю несколько колонок в базе данных как одну целую (это можно сказать как будто я пытаюсь это представить в виде массива и вытянуть индекс 0 в team_one_*, и индекс 1 в team_two_*)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140386/discussion-between---and-mike).

Comment: Я ответом написал как я это вижу. но тут что то не так с структурой таблиц. Сейчас в матче могут участвовать от 1 до бесконечности команд, что подозреваю не правильно

Comment: Знаю что в матче обычно могут участвовать бесконечное количество команд, однако могут быть только две команды, не три, не четыре, и не десять, а именно ДВЕ, по этому названия `team_one_*` и `team_two_*` в данном случае названия колонок `AS` можно использовать

Comment: *могут быть только две команды, не три, не четыре, и не десять, а именно ДВЕ* Сейчас ничто не мешает ввести данные матча, в котором участвовала одна команда, три команды и пр. Контроль - только со стороны клиентского кода, то есть фактически контроля просто нет. На что совершенно правильно указывает @Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM matches
  JOIN team_matches as team1 ON team1.match_id = matches.auto_id
  JOIN team_matches as team2
    ON team2.match_id = matches.auto_id and team2.auto_id < team1.auto_id
```

Поля в select расставить по вкусу.

Comment: Я кажется понял, как вы решили поступить.

Comment: Наверное, для более чёткого разделения логики связывания и логики отбора разумнее последнее условие переместить во WHERE - всё равно это ничего не изменит, ни результата, ни плана.

Comment: Я даже не знал что база данных может при указании одной и той же таблицы, но с условием выдавать разные результаты, спасибо очень сильно помогли!